# \n is not recognized when trying to define name in two lines

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple tabs, the name of the tab should appear in two lines.

Please find the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QPCgxgtkqtR4Z2LgXYrj?p=preview)
I tried to use \n while assigning the tabname but it didn't recognized.Any suggestions?
js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('tabs', [ 'ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('tabsctrl', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
          $rootScope.tabName ='MyTab Name';

    $rootScope.tabValue="tab1Value";
    $scope.applicationData = {};
    $scope.activeModule = "tab1Value";
    $scope.programModules=[{"tabName":"Tab1 Name \n Active Modules","tabValue":"tab1Value"},{"tabName":"Tab2 Name \n NonActive modules","tabValue":"tab2Value"}];
     //code     

});
```

In the tabname Active Modules and Non Active modules should be shown in second line of the tab as below.

```
  Tab1 Name            Tab2 Name  
Active Modules      Active Modules
```

--EDIT---
Please find the updated [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/3VBImpJyvAyyjS4iUkzH?p=preview) with the code mentioned in the below answer by jsalonen. I am getting the below error which can be seen in the console when plunker is opened,any suggestions to resolve this error:

```
angular.js:12477 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: tabName in pg.tabNames, Duplicate key: string:e, Duplicate value: e
```

Comment: Try using ```<br />``` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using new line(\n) in string and rendering the same in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573890/using-new-line-n-in-string-and-rendering-the-same-in-html)

Answer (score 5):

White spaces including line breaks are not rendered unless you either use a tag like `<pre>` that does that or explictly set that using white-space property in CSS:

```
.nav-tabs li {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

And besides, if you need assign more styling besides simple newline, I would instead encapsulate each of the text lines inside new elements (or just output `<br />` between each name field fraction). This would require you to tweak your code as follows.

Store tabnames as array:

```
$scope.programModules=[{"tabNames":["Tab1 Name Active Modules"],"tabValue":"tab1Value"},{"tabNames":["Tab2 Name", "NonActive modules"],"tabValue":"tab2Value"}];
```

Process them as array in template:

```
<div class="tabname-fraction" ng-repeat="tabName in pg.tabNames">
  {{tabName}}
</div>
```

For working code, see this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GgCORbr9mOn6iVA3EXiw?p=preview

Comment: Please find the updated link with your answer http://plnkr.co/edit/Uwg7ZiH9E3Gj5zGydTjs?p=preview. Its not working.Any suggestions.thanks

Comment: Can we do the same without modifying the code <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
            <li role="presentation" class="{{ pg.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="pg in programModules">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="loadApplicationData(pg.tabValue,pg.tabName)" >{{pg.tabName}}</a>
            </li> . As modifying the above code is breaking the tabs in my application.thanks

Comment: Yes we can. Use the CSS rule given in the first snippet. However: if your tab component has fixed height, then newlines will probably break those styles anyway. So you may need to change that component as well. For possible fix, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495828/bootstrap-3-tabs-with-two-liner-titles

Comment: This is the error message i'm getting Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: tabName in pg.tabNames, Duplicate key: string:i, Duplicate value: i

Comment: Please find the updated link http://plnkr.co/edit/3VBImpJyvAyyjS4iUkzH?p=preview which tracked the issue. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @joann you need to convert your tabName attribute to array. Otherwise repeater will interpret each character of your string as a new item.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. Is there any easier way to achieve this :). Being a newbie having touch time

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers ignore whitespace unless explicitly told otherwise.  This is a good thing, because it makes it easier to create readable HTML.

You're much better off using HTML elements if you want to create multi-line elements.

```
<li style='white-space:pre' role="presentation" class="{{ pg.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="pg in programModules">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="loadApplicationData(pg.tabValue,pg.tabName)" >{{pg.tabName}}
        <div ng-bind='pg.tabFirstLine'></div>
        <div ng-bind='pg.tabSecondLine'></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

You'll also need to change your data a little:

```
$scope.programModules=[{"tabFirstLine":"Tab1 Name","tabSecondLine": "Active Modules","tabValue":"tab1Value"},
    {"tabFirstLine":"Tab2 Name", "tabSecondLine": "NonActive modules","tabValue":"tab2Value"}];
```